# Clustering Python source code

Tags: python

I'd like to know if there is a (preferably open-source) library for clustering Python source code based on their similarity -- or alternatively, a code clone detector.

It should be based on algorithms (such as AST fingerprinting) on published papers, and should clearly describe it.

I'm adding that this is for clustering "Python source code", not clustering any data in general.

Comment: The sklearn documentation is pretty good, lists their 9 methods and gives published references for each one. You can check it in [this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

Comment: pretty sure PMD's CPD (Copy Paste Detector) can work with Python code, but that doesn't work at the AST level, so if you're looking to detect someone just renaming all the variables, that won't help

Comment: No, it does not. Check it here: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/cpd.html  (thanks for your reply though)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to cluster data together. I give 2 examples here.

**k-mean clustering**

You can use `scikit-learn` to cluster data into group using `KMeans` model. Basically each data points will be assigned into a group.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 2], [1, 1.5]])
kmean_model = KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=0)
kmean_model.fit_predict(X)

# return array([4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
```

k-mean clustering algorithm is available in most of books these day so you can reference to that.

**Hierarchical clustering**

For Hierarchical clustering, you have to find the distance matrix first, in this case will be 6 x 6 because we have 6 data points in `X`. The result we get will be partition number so you can rank your data points based on output partition.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster, linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 2], [1, 1.5]])
D = cdist(X, X) # euclidean distance matrix (you can custom distance here as you like)
linkage = linkage(D)
partition = fcluster(linkage, t=0.01, criterion='distance')

# return array([2, 1, 1, 5, 4, 3], dtype=int32)
```

See related papers [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html#references).

Comment: I meant clustering "Python source code", not clustering in Python.
Could you remove your answer, so that people recognise it as unanswered? (if you empty your reply, I'll remove my reply..)

Comment: @JohnJayDoe People will recognise the question as unanswered until you have accepted an answer.